# Switch user using password from file

Tags: users, password, su, input

how can i switch user using `su` command and adding password from file ? i want to make a script which will automaticly switch the user, having the user and the password ,instead of manually typing the password ?
P.S. I don't have super user rights.

Comment: the only way of  password less su , is to add the current user in the wheel group and then do `sudo su <user>` it ll not ask for password at all

Comment: @IjazKhan `sudo su` is a useless use of `su`. `sudo` swiches the user, the `su` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically programs like `su` require passwords to be entered on the terminal and can't be bypassed.  The `root` user doesn't need to enter a password to switch to another, so it's common to see solutions like `sudo su user`.

However we might be able to cheat.  If you have the `expect` command on your system then we can *fake* typing the password

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set user [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]

spawn /bin/su $user

expect "Password:"
send "$password\r";

interact
```

With this program you can do

```
./autosu username password
```

eg

```
% autosu root imnottellingyou
spawn su root
Password: 
[root@server /]#
```

It's not normally a good idea to do this exact thing, though, 'cos the password will appear in your shell history when you type it on the command line.  But if you have the password inside a script or data file then it doesn't matter too much!  You should be able to modify this simple example to meet your needs.

If you don't have `expect` installed then it gets harder; ask your admin to install it, or compile it from source and run it from your directory!

Answer (score 1):

The best option is use Sudo rulles
Safe passwords  in text file is in top 10 wrong pratice IT.
but if you want use you must rememebr parwd is not read from stdin but ftom tty 
so you can use `expect`(*1) but this is still wrong way . 
Beter option is use sudo or sshkey you can login to ssh account using public key to localhost address .

do not try  `su - username <<< password`

or

```
    su username << - _EOF_ 
    you_password 
    whoami
    _EOF_
```

this only can run command in another sheell and give you output.

*1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174337/trouble-logging-in-user-using-su-and-expect-script